# Extracting keys from JMESPath expression in objects

Tags: python, jquery, json, jmespath

I would like to extract the keys from those JSON objects in a  JMESPath expression:

```json
{"wrapperType": "track", "kind": "song", "artistId": 657515}
```

And this, independently of the values.

My main goal is to get something like this:

```json
["wrapperType", "kind", "artistId"]
```

I did find how to filter values without any problem but I am unable to find something that extracts keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [`keys` function](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#keys), that you can use on the current node: [`@`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#current-node).

On your example, running the query

```
keys(@)
```

Would give the expected JSON:

```json
[
  "wrapperType",
  "kind",
  "artistId"
]
```